# Can't show a model info in template

Tags: backbone.js

I would like to show my model in template, but I've a problem :

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: title is not defined
```

There's my code:

```
    var NewsView2 = Backbone.View.extend({

    NewsView: _.template(NewsView),

    initialize: function () {
                    console.log(this);
        this.$el.html(this.NewsView());
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {

        this.$el.html(this.NewsView());
        var html = this.NewsView(this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.append(html);
        return this;
    }

});
```

initialize:

```
            var news2 = new News({
            author: "costam",
        });
        var widok2 = new NewsView2({model: news2});
```

and code in my template:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
        <%= title %>
</body>
```

Someone could help me with that? I don't have any idea to do it.

Comment: What is `News` and where is it's constructor?  What is `NewsView`? where is the model? Why is your *template* a full HTML document? Why are you rendering inside `initialize`, `render` everywhere?

Comment: to be honest it looks like you have no idea what you're doing. Please go through some tutorials/books and documentation first.

Comment: I didn't send a full code, that's why there's no News etc. I thinked it's a trouble in view :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model doesn't have **title** property. UnderScore template is complaining because it tries to look for title property in your News model that doesn't exist.

Your Backbone View :

```
var NewsView2 = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function () {            
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {            
        var template = _.template($("#yourTemplate").html())            
        var html = template(this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.append(html);
        return this;
    }
});
```

Your Model :

```
var news2 = new News({ author: "costam", title : "Your title" });
```

Template :

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
   <script type="text/template" id="yourTemplate">
     <%= author %> // --> this should match/exist in your model 
     <%= title %> // --> this should match/exist in your model 
   </script>
</body>
```

Note : There are different ways to set backbone template like [this](http://kilon.org/blog/2012/11/3-tips-for-writing-better-backbone-views/).

Comment: Still not working, same error

Comment: I noticed there are something wrong with your codes. Fix some issue in basic way but I advise you to read some tutorials or book about backbone.

Comment: just added to template this.autor/this.title and working :)

Comment: ye, thanks you :) You just show me another way to set template :)